# Function in database for view current date fit this condition

Tags: sql, oracle, function, date, plsql

In this condition users can visit in a schedule.
How me to create a function in oracle database that have logic are:

- one month once visit (f1)
- two month once visit (f2)
- one week once visit (f4)
- one week twice visit(f8).

So we can view data in current date fit with that condition.

Example in database with table name is mst_callplan:

```
cust_no : 201, sales_no:001, frequent: f1, day: monday    
cust_no : 202, sales_no:001, frequent: f8, day: friday
cust_no : 203, sales_no:001, frequent: f2, day: wednesday
cust_no : 204, sales_no:001, frequent: f1, day: monday
```

cust_no,sales_no,frequent,and day is name of column.

From database will view row of table fit with that condition in current date. The data shown automatic when current date is change.

For the example result is: null (for this current date : 25/04/2017)

Help me for the function in database. how to create the function fit that condition.

Comment: Give some sample data, expected function calls and then expected output based on sample data.

Comment: Please edit your post to provide a [MCVE] including the DDL and DML statements for your tables and some sample data illustrating the problem and include your code to try to solve the problem and where it is incorrect and what you would expect. StackOverflow is **NOT** a code writing service.

Comment: Just rewording your plea is not the same as explaining what you want. Please provide sufficient sample data to satisfy all four rules, and show which rows are returned for different dates, and why. There are lots of people itching to write some code for you but they can only do so if you explain your requirements clearly.

Answer (score 0):

function in that case is:

```
     FUNCTION get_data_sales(pi_trxn_dt IN DATE)
        RETURN slm_type_mst_callplan_tab IS

    l_slm_type_mst_callplan_rec slm_type_mst_callplan_rec;
    l_slm_type_mst_callplan_tab slm_type_mst_callplan_tab := slm_type_mst_callplan_tab();

    l_return PLS_INTEGER;

    ex_set_date_lang EXCEPTION;

    CURSOR cur_data IS
      SELECT cust_id
            ,sales_id
            ,mst_freq
            ,mst_day
            ,start_date
            ,end_date
            ,week_no
      FROM mst_callplan
      WHERE (upper(mst_freq) = 'F1' and week_no=4 AND
            MOD(slm_pkg_utl.cnt_week(pi_start_dt => g_start_dt
                                     ,pi_end_dt   => pi_trxn_dt)
                ,4) = 0 AND upper(TRIM(mst_day)) = 
            upper(TRIM(to_char(pi_trxn_dt,'Day'))))

           OR
           (upper(mst_freq) = 'F1'and week_no=3 AND
            MOD(slm_pkg_utl.cnt_week(pi_start_dt => g_start_dt
                                     ,pi_end_dt   => pi_trxn_dt)
                ,4) = 3 AND upper(TRIM(mst_day)) = 
            upper(TRIM(to_char(pi_trxn_dt,'Day'))))

           OR
           (upper(mst_freq) = 'F1'and week_no=2 AND
            MOD(slm_pkg_utl.cnt_week(pi_start_dt => g_start_dt
                                     ,pi_end_dt   => pi_trxn_dt)
                ,4) = 2 AND upper(TRIM(mst_day)) = 
            upper(TRIM(to_char(pi_trxn_dt,'Day'))))

           OR
           (upper(mst_freq) = 'F1'and week_no=1 AND
            MOD(slm_pkg_utl.cnt_week(pi_start_dt => g_start_dt
                                     ,pi_end_dt   => pi_trxn_dt)
                ,4) = 1 AND upper(TRIM(mst_day)) = 
            upper(TRIM(to_char(pi_trxn_dt,'Day'))))

            OR
            (upper(mst_freq) = 'F2' and week_no=2 AND
            MOD(slm_pkg_utl.cnt_week(pi_start_dt => g_start_dt
                                     ,pi_end_dt   => pi_trxn_dt)
                ,2) = 0 AND upper(TRIM(mst_day)) =
            upper(TRIM(to_char(pi_trxn_dt
                                               ,'Day'))))
            OR
            (upper(mst_freq) = 'F2' and week_no=1 AND
            MOD(slm_pkg_utl.cnt_week(pi_start_dt => g_start_dt
                                     ,pi_end_dt   => pi_trxn_dt)
                ,2) = 1 AND upper(TRIM(mst_day)) =
            upper(TRIM(to_char(pi_trxn_dt,'Day'))))

            OR (upper(mst_freq) = 'F4' AND
            upper(TRIM(mst_day)) =
            upper(TRIM(to_char(pi_trxn_dt
                                  ,'Day'))))
            OR (upper(mst_freq) = 'F8' AND
            upper(TRIM(mst_day)) =
            upper(TRIM(to_char(pi_trxn_dt
                                  ,'Day'))));

  BEGIN
    set_date_language(po_return => l_return);
    IF l_return <> 0 THEN
      RAISE ex_set_date_lang;
    END IF;

    FOR rec_dt IN cur_data
    LOOP
      l_slm_type_mst_callplan_tab.extend;
      l_slm_type_mst_callplan_tab(l_slm_type_mst_callplan_tab.last) := slm_type_mst_callplan_rec(rec_dt.cust_id
                                                                                                ,rec_dt.sales_id
                                                                                                ,rec_dt.mst_freq
                                                                                                ,rec_dt.mst_day
                                                                                                ,rec_dt.start_date
                                                                                                ,rec_dt.end_date
                                                                                                ,rec_dt.week_no);

    END LOOP;
    RETURN l_slm_type_mst_callplan_tab;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN ex_set_date_lang THEN
      dbms_output.put_line('Error set date languange');
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      l_slm_type_mst_callplan_tab.delete;
  END get_data_sales;
```

Comment: Please edit your question and post the code snippet in the question.